# Core Graphics drawing multiple shapes

Tags: ios, drawing, core-graphics

I need to create an app that will allow you to add predefined shapes: circle, square, triangle, etc. to a view.

It is necessary that the user can manipulate the positions of the shapes, multi-select shapes, and move selected shapes that have already been added.

Would you use an `UIView` for each shape, or `CALayer`'s?

Answer (score 0):

For tis you can try UIGestureRecognizer,check this link may this will be helpful for you

[UIGestureRecognizer](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I have already implemented this functionality using `UIViews` with gesture recognizers but I was wondering about the pros and cons of using `UIViews` instead of `CALayers` for each separate shape. I know `CALayer` is a bit more lightweight than `UIView` but I'm not sure what other considerations I should take into account to compare the two approaches.